# Creating Active Directory of usernames for LDAP access

Tags: c#, ldap, adam, ldap-query, ldapconnection

I am a newbie to LDAP and Active Directories.

I need to build a active directory of users who are eligible to access a particular conputer. When the user enters the username and password in a web interface(created in C#)  it is sent to the active directory via LDAP query to the active directory. AD will return users email address if the login is successful.

Is it possible to setup a Active Directory  to achieve the above scenario locally? I am using Windows 7 Ultimate. I have installed ADAM for LDAP access.

Regards,

John.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

[Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// validate username/password combo
if (ctx.ValidateCredentials(username, password))
{
   // if valid - find user
   UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, username);

   if (user != null)
   {
                return user.EmailAddress;
   }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

For ADAM (or AD LDS as it's called today), you could use

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.ApplicationDirectory);
```

to establish a context with your ADAM directory - not sure, but you probably have to supply some form of additional information to know what Application directory to use (I've never played with this on ADAM). And also: I'm not sure if you can validate credentials against an ADAM store .... you'll just have to see and try!

Comment: Thanks marc_s. Is this the latest approach recommended by the Microsoft over System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry. I came across the following link which confused me. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/729d1214-37f5-4330-9208-bc4d9d695ad0/

Comment: @logeeks: yes, it's the latest/most recent MS library for using/working with Active Directory.